# Matching values for a list in python

Tags: python, list, while-loop

Beginner question:  I am trying to evaluate whether two values in a row match.

```
a = ['sl','sl','cr','cl']
```

This is my current code:

```
while (j+1) < len(a):
    if a[j] == a[j+1]:
        num = num + 1
    else: 
        num = num
```

However, when I do it this way it doesn't count the first value in the list - this is due to (j+1), however, if I remove it, get an error telling me my index is out of range - any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `num = len(a) - len(set(a))`? Note that the `else` can be dropped, and your approach only checks immediate neighbours.

Comment: Start from 0, count up to 1 less than the last index. @MosesKoledoye are you missing another len there? :)

Comment: What if a value is present 3 times? Do you want to increment the counter once or twice?

Comment: That also cannot be your current code, as you never really increment j.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Do you mean `num = len(a) - len(set(a))`? Also, OP's question is about "two values in a row", i.e. immediate neighbors.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I assumed `a` is the row which is supposedly part of a larger list of lists (like those from a `csv.reader`). I think OP needs to confirm this

Comment: What would the result of `a = ['sl','sl','sl','cr','cl', 'bob']` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you should improve in your code.
First, loop over [enumerate(list)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to easily compare items in the list.
Second, `IndexError` can be used to quit the loop after the last index is reached.
Here an --easy-to-read-- example.

```
for i,item in enumerate(a):
    try:
        if item = a[i+1]:
            print(item, 'and', a[i+1], 'are the same')
            #increment your counter here
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Comment: You could always loop over `enumerate(a[:-1])` to avoid the `IndexErrror` in the first place. Or `a[1:]` and use the previous value instead of the next... (also you might want to use `==` in the `if`)

Comment: @Baldrickk Indeed, that is a good suggestion for a beginner. I prefer my way, I find it more explicit, but thanks!